# extracting individual email from a single thunderbird email data file

Tags: python, regex, parsing, email, thunderbird

I have a thunderbird email data file from which I need to extract individual email. I tried to use regex and do plain vanilla extract based on from tag but this doesn't give me the required result. An email can have another email attached within the body hence a single email can have more than one "From:" strings. How can I extract individual emails out of this data file?

Comment: What format does Thunderbird store messages in on disk? If it uses mbox/maildir, the python mailbox module can help http://docs.python.org/library/mailbox.html

Comment: It used to use [Mork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mork_%28file_format%29), but may have migrated to some SQLite solution these days.

Comment: @codeape, you sir are a day saver, :-) thanks a ton, please post this as an answer so that I can select it and close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [python mailbox module](http://docs.python.org/library/mailbox.html).

The mailbox module can read mbox/maildir message stores.